# In masstransit, how can I set the current culture to the message being executed?

Tags: .net, masstransit

I'm developing a dotnet api and already have all the Localization features implemented, but when processing a message from the queue, the CurrentCulture/CurrentUiCulture is not being set correctly, thus the IStringLocalizer ressources are being retrieved in a unwanted culture.

I'm using masstransit with AmazonSQS.

On the web api project, my localization config is like this:

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureLocalization(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    return serviceCollection.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), };

            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("pt-BR");

            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;

            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        })
        .AddLocalization();
}
```

On another project I have my Masstransit consumers like:

```
public class UserConsumers : IConsumer<IRunTestMessage>
{
    private readonly ILogger<UserConsumers> _logger;
    private readonly IUserHandlers _userHandlers;

    public UserConsumers(ILogger<UserConsumers> logger, IUserHandlers userHandlers)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _userHandlers = userHandlers;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IRunTestMessage> context)
    {
        await _userHandlers.RunTestAsync(context.Message.UserId);
    }
}
```

When any message is received, the CurrentCulture/CurrentUiCulture is always 'en-US'.

How can I set the CurrentUiCulture per message received?

Answer (score 1):

To pass the culture, you would need to capture the culture for the UserId and store that either in a message header or in the message (probably the first one) and then use that value to select the culture to use while consuming the message.

There is no built-in facility that will automatically transfer the culture from the message originator to the consumer.

Comment: Adding to that, I end up implementing an ```DefaultCulturePipeSpecification<T> : IPipeSpecification<T> ``` that reads the culture info header and set the CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture. Thank you